# How to copy using Multiple filter from user inputbox data in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

[image]

I would like to get more than 1 input from user via inputbox and filter the table. Only one column is filtered. Then copy the entire row data to another sheet. I used the code below. The problem is it can be used to filter 1 country.

I have plenty of countries in column F. I need to enter 2 or more countries in inputbox. Then copy and paste. I would like to add Loop. But i dont know how. Help me

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim str1 As Variant
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim RngArea As Range

Set Tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("DataTable")
str1 = Application.InputBox("Select the Country Code")

If str1 = False Then
    MsgBox "Please select one Country", , "Input"
Exit Sub

Else

Tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=str1
For Each RngArea In Tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If RngArea.Row > 1 Then
    If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
        Set FiltRng = Application.Union(FiltRng, RngArea)
    Else
        Set FiltRng = RngArea
    End If
End If

Next RngArea

If Not FiltRng Is Nothing Then
FiltRng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
End If

End If

Sheet1.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6

End Sub
```

Comment: The starting point for any request like this should be "Fire up the macro recorder, perform a filter, and see what code it spits out".

Comment: @jeffreyweir It is like this.   'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=  Array("AT", "BY", "DE", "FI", "GI"), Operator:=xlFilterValues'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read from InputBox in a loop. Try the following code.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim size As Long
    size = 1

    Do
        str1 = Application.InputBox("Select the Country Code")

        ReDim Preserve arr(size)
        arr(size) = str1
        size = size + 1
    Loop While (str1 <> vbNullString) And (str1 <> False)

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$F$5").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad I help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply make a PivotTable out of the data, put the PivotTable in the other sheet, and add a slicer so that users can select the countries that they want? No VBA necessary.

Comment: I don't need pivot. I need to do in VBA

Answer (score 1):

Use the following sub which take two criteria to filter the table and copy filtered data to `sheet2`. You can add more criteria as you need.

```
Sub Filter2Criteria()
Dim str1, str2 As Variant
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim FiltRng As Range
Dim RngArea As Range

    Set Tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("DataTable")

    str1 = Application.InputBox("Select the Country Code")
    str2 = Application.InputBox("Select the Country Code")

    If str1 = False Then
        MsgBox "Please select first Country", , "Input"
          Exit Sub
          ElseIf str2 = False Then
         MsgBox "Please select second Country", , "Input"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=str1, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=str2

    Set FiltRng = Tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    FiltRng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

End Sub
```